# I cannot start any port with Motoko

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, motoko

I am trying to learn Motoko, i wrote following simply code;

```
import Debug "mo:base/Debug"

actor DBank {
  var currentValue = 300;
  let id = 12423532415345;
      Debug.print(debug_show(currentValue));


  public func topUp() {
    currentValue += 1;
    Debug.print(debug_show(currentValue));
  }
}
```

Then, I first, started it by `dfx start`, then I deployed by `dfx deploy`.

After that, I created the candid and I got the key with the command of `dfx canister id __Candid_UI`

But I cannot lunch the page with http://127.0.0.1:8000/?canisterId=

Can you please help me to resolve this?

I tried the instructions on the following page;
https://internetcomputer.org/docs/current/developer-docs/backend/candid/candid-howto

and I got nothing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `dfx deploy`? Especially the lines after `URLs:` (if this line is present).

Comment: Hello,

Since its too long to share, here its screenshoot;

https://www.imgup.cam/ib/qIQKaxZauy.png

Comment: For your information concerning [using screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Have you tried to open URLs under `URLs:`, as they don't mention the `8000` port that you mention in your question but the `4943` one?